# How am I violating this constraint?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have this constraint in a table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InventoryLocations]
(
    [recid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LocItemNumber] [char](16) NOT NULL,
    [WareHouse] [char](2) NOT NULL,
    [Aisle] [char](3) NOT NULL,
    [Slot] [char](3) NOT NULL,
    [locLevel] [char](2) NOT NULL,
    [Bin] [char](2) NOT NULL,
    [Extra] [char](2) NOT NULL,
    [LocNumber] [char](2) NOT NULL,
    [RollNumber] [char](20) NOT NULL,
    [QuickRoll] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SkidNumber] [char](15) NOT NULL,
    [RollsInStock] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LocQtyOnHand] [float] NOT NULL,
    [LocQtyOnOrder] [float] NOT NULL,
    [LocQtyCommited] [float] NOT NULL,
    [TotalReceived] [float] NOT NULL,
    [TotalIssued] [float] NOT NULL,
    [TotalDollars] [float] NOT NULL,
    [Capacity] [float] NOT NULL,
    [AvailableSpace] [float] NOT NULL,
    [bkey0] [char](30) NULL,
    [bkey1] [char](30) NULL,
    [bkey2] [char](30) NULL,
    [bkey3] [char](14) NULL,
    [LastPhysicalCountDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [LastCycleCountDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [EnteredBy] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [EnteredDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [IX_InventoryLocations_1] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [LocItemNumber] ASC,
    [WareHouse] ASC,
    [Aisle] ASC,
    [Slot] ASC,
    [locLevel] ASC,
    [Bin] ASC,
    [Extra] ASC,
    [RollNumber] ASC,
    [SkidNumber] ASC
));
```

And when trying to insert the following rows, I get the error message.
Inside a cursor which populates the variables.

```
INSERT INTO [AVANTISERVER\NCL_MASTER].[Avanti].[dbo].[InventoryLocations](LocItemNumber, WareHouse, Aisle, Slot, locLevel, Bin, Extra, RollNumber, LocQtyOnHand, SkidNumber)
            SELECT @item, 'F', 'L', 'E', 'X', 'O', @seq, @seq, @qty, @seq
            FROM FI_CurrentReceiptData CR
```

Which works out to:

```
VALUES('MW1', 'F', 'L', 'E', 'X', 'O', 0, 0, 10, 0)
VALUES('MW1', 'F', 'L', 'E', 'X', 'O', 1, 1, 10, 1)
```

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 2, Line 34 Violation of UNIQUE KEY
>   constraint 'IX_InventoryLocations_1'. Cannot insert duplicate key in
>   object 'InventoryLocations'.

Please help me to understand why I cannot make these insertions?  I am not experienced with these sort of complex constraints.  What does this one mean (in simple terms) and how can I get around it?  Am I actually violating the constraint?

Comment: Can you show the schema for the table, or is it exactly as shown in the constraint definition? Can you also show the exact `INSERT` statement (or does it not include column names anyway)? Note that the constraint violation might not be coming from a clash in the two rows you are inserting, but one or both key combinations may already exist in the table.

Comment: Is LocItemNumber the primary key for the table?

Comment: Your `values` clause now bears no relation to your table structure. What is the actual code that fails?

Comment: @James Johnson -No, see table schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the items in your `SELECT` list are constant expressions.

```
INSERT INTO [AVANTISERVER\NCL_MASTER].[Avanti].[dbo].[InventoryLocations](LocItemNumber, WareHouse, Aisle, Slot, locLevel, Bin, Extra, RollNumber, LocQtyOnHand, SkidNumber)
            SELECT @item, 'F', 'L', 'E', 'X', 'O', @seq, @seq, @qty, @seq
            FROM FI_CurrentReceiptData CR
```

I'm not sure why you expect it to differ between rows but in any event it won't. Perhaps you meant to reference a column rather than a variable somewhere.

As you say in the comments these variables are being updated in a cursor presumably your `SELECT` is returning multiple rows `FROM FI_CurrentReceiptData`. Comment out the Insert and look at the results and see how many rows are returned. Or just remove `FROM FI_CurrentReceiptData CR` entirely as the `SELECT` doesn't use anything from it.

Comment: The insert statement is inside a cursor (as stated in my edits).

Comment: Well presumably your `SELECT` is returning multiple rows `FROM FI_CurrentReceiptData`. Comment out the Insert and look at the results.

Comment: ...or one or more of the key combinations is already represented in the table. I think the OP is focusing on the data that's coming out of the cursor but not comparing it to data that's already in the table.

Comment: @Martin Smith -I got lost in my code revisions.  The select was from a previous version, obviously I need to use an actual Values clause within a cursor.  Only reason I posted a values clause was because its a real pain to post a table (even a small one) on SO.

Comment: +1, nice to finally see the actual code. Maybe just the FROM shouldn't be there, if the variables are populated from a cursor over that same table.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand -Select clause changed to values, and from removed did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

do you already have rows in the table that conflict with the data from your question that you are trying to insert?

**EDIT** after comments and question edit
add this:

put some prints in your loop to see what values you're inserting. I don't think SQL Server will issue an error unless you are trying to insert dups.

Comment: @KM -No, there are no locItemNumber's 'MW1' in the table before inserts.

Comment: your edit on the question shows that there are MANY columns in the table, but you only give half of the insert, where is the column list?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the names of the columns you're trying to `INSERT`, just by the **number** of columns listed in your constraint (9) it looks like each row must be **completely** unique in the table `InventoryLocations`.  You're inserting (10) columns.  Your constraint is defined wrong based on the data you want to add.

**EDIT**: After your table definition edits, you still have too many columns listed in the `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` which is causing the `INSERT` failure. It would really help if you listed the column names you're inserting to.

**EDIT**: You are inserting hard-coded values into columns listed in your constraint. Since they will always be the same the constraint is violated and you see the error you posted. You need to either vary the data going into the table or relax the constraint by removing some of the columns.

Comment: -Constraint cannot be violated by that, because the table already has many records which are the same but for only 1 field in the constraint.

Answer (score -1):

You have to let us know the first part of the `INSERT`, not only the values. However, it's easy to tell that what is happening, basically, is that you are trying to insert a record that will violate `[IX_InventoryLocations_1]` which states that no 2 records on the table can have the same values for the following fields:

```
[LocItemNumber]
[WareHouse]
[Aisle]
[Slot]
[locLevel]
[Bin]
[Extra]
[RollNumber]
[SkidNumber]
```

Comment: 7th and 8th are different too.

Comment: That's not true, the 7th and 8th are different as well. And I assume that the first column in the insert statement isn't actually defined in the constraint.

Comment: The original version showed the 7th and 8th fields as different, too.

Comment: @Adrian -Ok, according to constraint, what data is invalid?  I have no problem changing some of the imput data, I'm just trying to satisfy the existing table.  I won't be using all of these fields.

Comment: ? If you go through the history of the edits, the 7th and 8th values were different from the very beginning, so your postulation that the first nine values all have the same in both `INSERT`s was not correct before the edit, either. :-(

Comment: @Adrian -So this constaint means that I can have 2 records with the same data in all of those fields except for 1?

Comment: @Adrian - I'm looking for an excuse to upvote this but at the moment it really just restates the question in a different way. It just tells the OP that they must be violating the constraint. It doesn't provide any explanation as to how.